# XP Pro x64: Program started at boot with automatic logon behave differently after update

Tags: windows-xp, boot, credentials, 64-bit

I have a program that I wrote in .NET to select games for mame (arcade emulator). This is a frontend. I configured in the registry an automatic logon for the administrator. In the "startup" windows folder, I added a shortcut to my program.

My program then launch at boot time and I can select a game from the menu. The program then spawns a process to execute "mame.exe" with the game I chose. Everything worked fine for several months.

I updated my Windows XP Pro x64 the other day and since then, when I choose a game, the process "mame.exe" is spawned but its frozen (I have to do end task on the spawned mame.exe, the game never starts).

It does it only when I try it immediately after the automatic logon (when the frontend was started by the "startup" folder at boot time) When I start my frontend manually after a boot, everything works fine. I'm suspecting credentials issue when the frontend is started by the system at boot?

There's so many patch installed that I don't know which one to uninstall to return to my previous state.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer, but +1 for mame. Emulation rules! ;)

Comment: You'll then love my Arcade :) http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=1812943&l=c3cca7dfaf&id=734330167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when they got installed. Delete just the ones which came recently or mentions this. You should also have a System Restore point to roll back.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've installed something like 80 fixes... I'll check if I have not disabled the system restore.

Comment: Well..you should use system update constantly..not just occasionally. :))

Comment: Yeah but since it is an Arcade and nothing more, I don't have the habit to update too often lol

Comment: Oh.. well if it doesn't have an internet connection nor USB stuff comes in, just leave it as it is and use a rollback application which rolls back everything like it was before the last boot.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, I'll try to have an understanding before marking it as the answer..

Comment: What do you mean by that? :)

Comment: I want to know exactly what is causing the problem lol.. I really think it's a security issue if the system starts the program versus myself.

Comment: Hmm in my opinion you should make drive images. There are many good utilities there (guess you can also find some questions here about that) which can make a disk image and restore it using a bootable disk. It'd be perfect for times like these.. right? :)

Comment: By the way, on Windows, system = you. You = system. Both have admin right by default (only if you didn't use a limited access user). You can also use the "/RunAs" parameter. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Cool thaks for everything

Comment: Oh, no problem. Good luck.